# Using Office for Mac 2016 to edit a document using WebDAV

Tags: macos, office365, webdav

I had to rebuild my Mac and installed Office for Mac 2016 (from an Office 365 subscription).  I am not able to click on a link on a web page and edit the document with WebDAV (iTHit implementation not SharePoint).  I was using Office for Mac 2011 before the rebuild and that was working...When I clicked on the link using Safari, the pop up for allowing the SharePoint browser plug-in did not display.  Since the site I am connecting to uses basic authentication over a non-SSL connection, I used Terminal and ran the following command: defaults -currentHost write com.microsoft.registrationDB hkey_current_user\hkey_local_machine\software\microsoft\office\15.0\common\internet\basicauthlevel -int 2
I was not able to have the document open with Word.
I uninstalled Office for Mac 2016 and deleted and file that reference Microsoft..Then I installed Office for Mac 2011 and ran the command above with \14.0\ instead of \15.0\.  I can edit documents with WebDAV.
What settings will allow the use of Office for Mac 2016?

Comment: OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 and Safari 8.0.7

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar problem and trying to open / edit office documents from the browser via WebDAV / Sharepoint plugin. This used to work with prior office versions, but not with Office 2016.

Apparently Microsoft dropped the WebDAV support for Office 2016 which would also affect the itHit library: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2016-macword/using-office-for-mac-2016-to-edit-a-document-from/2aee8656-313a-4c97-8223-9a20373b9891

Answer (score 0):

We have retested IT Hit WebDAV Ajax Library and Ajax File Browser with Office for Mac 2016.

**Opening and saving MS Office documents from a web page works just fine. The Word, Excel and PowerPoint documents opened from server successfully, edited and saved back directly to server with no problem.**

For testing we were using MS Office for Mac Version 15.22 (160506) with default install options and ajaxbrowser.com running Ajax File Browser v3.0.0.2465 (WebDAV Ajax Library v2.0.1735) as a testing server. The MS Office was installed on a clean Mac v10.11.3 that did not have MS Office 2011 installed previously, so there is no any remains of protocols installed by MS Office 2011. There is also no IT Hit Edit Document Opener installed on this machine.

The confusion around WebDAV being not supported is probably caused by a new MS Office "Save As..." dialog that shows the WebDAV location from which the document is opened but it does not allow browsing WebDAV folders. Even though, saving under new name in the same folder works well in "Save As" dialog.

Comment: Have you also done the tests on OSX Sierra? We cannot get ITHit WebDAV to work on one Mac with Office 2016 and OSX sierra, but works fine with El Capitan.